# How to render an error page called error.html when user searches a query that does not exist at all using django

Tags: python, search, django-views, django-forms, wikipedia

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQeQO.png)ive been having issues trying to implement the error message i want in search. just like typing up a page  path that doesnt exist will return error.html, i want to do the same when you search a query that doesnt exist. Mind you, if they search something like "py", since python is an entry that exists it just returns a page with the link to python. That parts fine. Now I want to do it so that if they search something like "java", since there is no entry that exist that contains the word java i.e "java", "javascript" etc, i want it to return the error page i have created but it doesnt do that.
ive tried all i can but it doesnt work

i tried this

```
error= {"message": "ERROR: This entry does not exist" }
entries = util.list_entries()

def search(request):
    searchquery= request.POST['q']
    content= md_to_html(searchquery)
    file= {"title": searchquery , "content": content }
    empty_list= []

    if util.get_entry(searchquery):
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/entry.html", file )

    else:
        for entry in entries:
            if searchquery.lower() in entry.lower():
                empty_list.append(entry)
            did_you_mean = {"did_you_mean": empty_list}
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/search.html", did_you_mean)

    return render(request, "encyclopedia/search.html", error)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i want to render an error page when a user searches for something that does not exist as an entry in my server.